# Erro no .First(), pois não existe resultado selecionado

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

No meu *controller* de *Login* utilizo o seguinte código para fazer a seleção do usuário caso exista, porém sempre que ele o usuário digita o nome ou senha incorreto, ele dá um erro, pois não encontra o resultado para o `.First`. Preciso fazer um tratamento, para quando não encontrar nenhum resultado não dá esse erro.

```
var user = db.Usuario.First(u => u.Nome == model.Nome && u.Senha.Equals(model.Senha));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem algumas soluções para isto, uma delas é usar o [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

```
var user = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Nome == model.Nome && u.Senha.Equals(model.Senha));
```

Obviamente você terá que tratar o resultado depois se não existir nenhum usuário compatível com o que foi informado, afinal, o resultado será um `null` se não achar nada, sem um tratamento, só estará empurrando o problema mais pra frente. Mas fazendo assim, usará o fluxo normal. Algo do tipo:

```
if (user == null) return false;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/First.cs).